# Obtain a maximum value from a Column separated by interval 192.using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file that contains almost 34739 rows and two columns. The rows are separated by blank Row after every interval of 192 rows. Now, I want to find maximum values from each interval in the second Column. And write the output value in .csv

Kindly Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` library for this

If you don't have pandas installed, install it with the command `pip install pandas`

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> #Assuming that you have data like this, instead of 192 rows, i am using 3 rows
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> data = StringIO("""Col1,Col2
... 2,5
... 5,6
... 4,6
...
... 1,4
... 3,6
... 2,8
... """)
```

Read the csv using pandas

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(data)
>>> df
   Col1  Col2
0     2     5
1     5     6
2     4     6
3     1     4
4     3     6
5     2     8
```

Group them

```
>>> df['groups'] = df.index//3
>>> df
   Col1  Col2  groups
0     2     5       0
1     5     6       0
2     4     6       0
3     1     4       1
4     3     6       1
5     2     8       1
```

Find the maximum of each group.

```
>>> df.groupby('groups').max()
        Col1  Col2
groups
0          5     6
1          3     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `pandas` and `numpy`

### import

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

### read csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep='\t')
```

### find max using numpy

```
a = np.array(df['Value'])
b = np.argwhere(np.isnan(a)).flatten()
[np.nanmax(c) for c in np.split(a, b, axis=0)]
```